# whats the best way to turn ubuntu 12.10 to a simple fileserver for backups?

Tags: file-sharing

I have an old rig that I am trying to 1) learn linux and terminal/bash 2) make it into a simple fileserver so that I can mirror my documents  through LAN. More specifically I will be  using it in an office environment so I can not use Dropbox for example since it goes through their servers (my files are very confidential).

So I would like dropbox like functionality where a file change on my business machine (windows 8) is mirrored to an ubuntu box. Actually I am okay with periodic backup also rather then as soon as I hit "ctrl s" it starts a backup - this actually might not be a good idea considering the harddrives are slow and old and running them a lot is just asking for problems and failure.

Please let me know the easiest root with possible instructions.

EDIT: I think what I am looking for is Samba. After I install samba it will give me a readable/writable folder on my linux machine. I will be able to access this location through explorer in windows.

My next question is: does there exist a backup software that I can manually type in the folder location?

EDIT 2: I believe that syncing to the cloud is also possible as long as the files are being encrypted before they are sent. Any way to incorporate this ? 
Thanks

Comment: The scope of your question is huge. One could write long manuals or even books to cover the server+backup topic. Try scaling it down to something more answerable within the scope of a single post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is your business computer at an office somewhere outside of your house, where your Ubuntu machine will be?

(Sorry, this should be a comment but I don't have comment privileges)

**Edit 1**: Since everything connected through LAN, Samba could be a workable option. It's not going to be great though, because it has sync feature. You would have to mount a network folder (Easy), and then manually store documents that you need backed up in that network folder (Labor intensive).

If you need to sync *many* documents that are changing *often*, then you should look for a more advanced synchronization tool. For a start, try [this](https://superuser.com/questions/65524/how-do-synchronise-two-folders-in-windows-7-in-real-time) SuperUser thread. Remember, once you have mounted the shared folder (on ubuntu machine) into your Windows file system, you can treat it as a local directory, so all you need is software that keeps two *local* directories in sync.

Comment: No everything is connected through LAN. I might do business outside my office, but to sync right away is not necessary until I step into the office.

Comment: I crossposted this to superuser. I've found my solution -Unison, works great but have to initiate the sync manually, which is fine. http://superuser.com/questions/542213/making-use-of-cloud-backup-and-filesyncing-wih-client-side-encryption

Comment: Great. Maybe checkmark the solution to mark this thread as solved?

Comment: Yes I will. Please edit your answer to include Unison and possibly a link to the superuser thread incase someone else comes upon this thread. 

Thanks